# Querying the reverse relation of a foreign key in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models

So, I have a model `Event` which has a foreign key `venue` to a model `EventVenue` (the related name is set to `events`). `Event`, along other fields, has a boolean field called `free`.

If I want to get all the venues that have at least one free Event, that's just:

```
EventVenue.objects.filter(events__free=True)
```

But how do I get the venues where all of its events are free? Can I do it in an easy way?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can exclude the `EventVenue`s that have a non-free event, with:

```
EventVenue.objects.exclude(events__free=False)
```